# Kivy Selection on Focus

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to have kivy select the text of a TextInput widget on focus but when I try it seems to select it when it unfocuses and retains the selection. Any ideas how I can select it on focus and on unfocus deselect? I've attached my code below if someone wants to have a play around.

kv file:

```
<TextInput>:
    size_hint: 0.9, 0.5
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    multiline: False

<Button>:
    text: "Press Me"
    size_hint: (0.1, 0.5)
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

<MainLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.15, 0.15, 0.16, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 10

        BoxLayout:
            padding: 10
            TextInput:
                text: "Directory"
            Button:
                text: "Browse"
                on_press: root.browse_btn()

        BoxLayout:
            padding: 10
            TextInput:
                text: "Prefix"
                on_focus: self.select_all()
            TextInput:
                text: "File"
                on_focus: self.select_all()
            TextInput:
                text: "Suffix"
                on_focus: self.select_all()

        BoxLayout:
            padding: 10
            Button:
                id: button_one
                text: "Confirm"
                on_press: root.confirm_btn()
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_press: root.cancel_btn()
```

python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)


class MainLayout(BoxLayout):
    button_id = ObjectProperty(None)

    def browse_btn(self):
        print("Hey")

    def confirm_btn(self):
        print("Confirm")

    def cancel_btn(self):
        print("Cancel")


class BatchRenameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "Batch File Rename"
        Window.size = (750, 250)
        return MainLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = BatchRenameApp()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well hidden in the `TextInput` documentation:

> Selection is cancelled when TextInput is focused. If you need to show
>   selection when TextInput is focused, you should delay (use
>   Clock.schedule) the call to the functions for selecting text
>   (select_all, select_text).

So, in your `kv`, start by importing `Clock`:

```
#: import Clock kivy.clock.Clock
```

Then you can use it in a `TextInput` rule:

```
        TextInput:
            text: "Prefix"
            on_focus: Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.select_all()) if self.focus else None
```

The `if self.focus` makes sure the `select_all` only happens when the `TextInput` gains focus.

Comment: Yea it isn't very obvious how to manage that. I did have the clock function in initially but it was doing the same thing definitely didn't think of adding the if statement but that fixes my problem! Thanks!